# How to print a dictionary separated by commas

Tags: python, dictionary, formatting

Let's say we have a dictionary

```
dict = { 'Dollar': 12, 'Half-Coin': 4, 'Quarter': 3, 'Dime': 7 }
```

How would I go about printing the code so it looks like:

> Dollar 12,  Half-Coin 4, Quarter 3, Dime 7

Comment: Writing code would be a good start... You show what you've done to attemp this yourself, we'll (maybe) try help fix it. Anything else is simply us doing your job for you.

Comment: You can use a list comprehension to concat your entries and then join them with the str.join() function. Look it up ;)

Answer (score 5):

Use `','.join()`, passing in a generator of strings.

```
d = { 'Dollar': 12, 'Half-Coin': 4, 'Quarter': 3, 'Dime': 7 }
print ', '.join('{} {}'.format(k,v) for k,v in d.items())
```

Result:

```
Half-Coin 4, Quarter 3, Dollar 12, Dime 7
```

If you want the results to be in a predictable order, you'll need to sort the items.

```
order=('Dollar', 'Half-Coin', 'Quarter', 'Dime')
d = { 'Dollar': 12, 'Half-Coin': 4, 'Quarter': 3, 'Dime': 7 }
print ', '.join('{} {}'.format(k,d[k]) for k in sorted(d, key=order.index))
```

Result:

```
Dollar 12, Half-Coin 4, Quarter 3, Dime 7
```

Ps. Don't name your variables with names of builtin types. Your name eclipses the builtin name, so subsequent code won't be able to call `dict()`, for example.

Comment: Thank you, it works! However, I don't understand how "for k,v in d.items())" works in conjunction with the rest of the code. What is being separated out?

Comment: `d.items()` returns a sequence of two-element tuples. The first element of each tuple is a dictionary key. The second item is a dictionary value. The phrase `for k,v in d.items()` indicates a loop which successively assigns the key to `k` and the value to `v` for each item in the dictionary. (I don't know what you mean by "separated out".)

Answer (score -1):

```
dict = { 'Dollar': 12, 'Half-Coin': 4, 'Quarter': 3, 'Dime': 7 }

out=""
for i in dict:
    out += i+" "+str(dict[i])+", "

print out[:-2]
```

result:

```
Half-Coin 4, Quarter 3, Dollar 12, Dime 7
```

Answer (score -1):

```
", ".join([x +" "+str(dict[x]) for x in dict.keys()])
```